# How to use apostrophe (') in xpath while finding element using webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I need to use apostrophe (') in my xpath expression which i need to use in finding elements using webdriver

i need to use below Xpath expression

```
//input[@text="WE'd like to hear from you"]
```

while using the above expression in find elements function i am replacing double quotes with single quotes

```
driver.findelements(By.xpath("//input[@text='WE'd like to hear from you']"))
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Use the xpath as shown below:

```
driver.findElements(By.xpath("//input[contains(@text,\"WE'd\")]"));
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: In my case, the text I get is dynamic either with single quotes or without. How would we handle dynamically

Answer (score 7):

You have to use double-quotes as your *XPath string literal delimiter*, since XPath 1.0 doesn't provide a way of escaping quotes. In addition to that, you can escape the double-quotes in Java, to avoid it from conflicting with your *Java string delimiter*, which also use double-quotes :

```
driver.findelements(By.xpath("//input[@text=\"WE'd like to hear from you\"]"))
```

Answer (score 4):

The Escape character usage does not serve the purpose. I tried the concatenation function and it worked like a charm. Please see the below xpath.

> tag: li Manager of Workflow Initiator's Manager /li

Concatenate function and split the string as –

```
concat('Manager of Workflow Initiator',"'",'s Manager')
```

**Single quote** is kept in **double quote** while other characters are kept in single quotes..

So XPath looks as –

```
//li[.=concat('Manager of Workflow Initiator',"'",'s Manager')]
```

Comment: if the above solution doesn't work then use the below solution using escape sequence.

xpath: //li[.=\"Manager of Workflow Initiator's Manager\"]

Here we are treating the whole text as a string.

Comment: This is a great general solution that can be used for a function that will escape arbitrary strings that might contain single and double quotes.

Answer (score 1):

if the above solution doesn't work then use the below solution using escape sequence.

```
xpath: //li[.=\"Manager of Workflow Initiator's Manager\"]
```

Here we are treating the whole text as a string using the escape character

Answer (score 0):

I Encountered a similar situation where I need to write an xpath for an element shown below:

**Element:**

```
<img src="webwb/pzspacer.gif!!.gif" class="inactvIcon" data-ctl="["DatePicker"]" style="cursor:pointer;">
```

I was able to grep the element using below Xpath, where I used the backslash to escape the characters [ and  ".

**Xpath** : `//img[@data-ctl='\[\"DatePicker\"\]']`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

None of the above approaches cover a situation where both Quote and Apostrophe cos exist. I've created a function for that,

```
driver.findElements(By.xpath(String.format("//input[contains(@text,%s))]"),escapeQuotes(textVal));
```

Implemenatation of the escape Quote.

```
private String escapeQuotes(String text) {

    // If we don't have any Quote then enquote string in Quote
    if (!text.contains("\"")) {
        return String.format("\"%s\"", text);
    }

    // If we have some Quote but no Apostrophe then enquote in Apostrophe
    if (!text.contains("'")) {
        return String.format("'%s'", text);
    }

    // If input is like Administr"ati'on then we have both " and ' in the string so must use Concat
    // we will be building the xPath like below and let the browser xPath evaluation to handle the concatenation
    // output : concat('Administr\"',\"ati'on\")
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("concat(");

    // Looking for " as they are LESS likely than '
    int lastPos = 0;
    int nextPos = text.indexOf("\"");
    while (nextPos != -1) {
        // If this is not the first time through the loop then seperate arguments with ,
        if (lastPos != 0) {
            sb.append(",");
        }

        sb.append(String.format("\"%s\",'\"'", text.substring(lastPos, nextPos - lastPos)));
        lastPos = ++nextPos;

        // Find next occurrence
        nextPos = text.indexOf("\"", lastPos);
    }

    sb.append(String.format(",\"%s\")", text.substring(lastPos)));
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm working with c# and Selenium, only way that worked for me was by splitting the string at (') and combine them using `concat` function. This is a small method I used to achieve my goal.

This method takes two input parameters: `inputString` and `originalXpath`.

If `inputString` does not contain any single quotes, the method simply returns the `originalXpath` string formatted with the `inputString` parameter using the `string.Format()` method.

If `inputString` does contain single quotes, the method replaces each single quote with `', "'", '` using the `Replace()` method and concatenates the resulting string with the `concat()` function. It then replaces the placeholder `' {0} '` in the `originalXpath` string with the `replacementString` created in the previous step using the `Replace()` method. Finally, the method returns the resulting string.

In summary, this method formats an XPath string with an input parameter, using a `concat()` function to handle cases where the input parameter contains single quotes.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string originalXpath = "//div[contains(., '{0}')]";
        string inputString = "bjhe'bf83785*^{}^$#%!'edferferf'034**()";
        string output = FormatWithConcat(inputString, originalXpath);
        Console.WriteLine(output); 
        // Output: //div[contains(., concat('bjhe', "'", 'bf83785*^{}^$#%!', "'", 'edferferf', "'", '034**()'))]
    }
    
    private static string FormatWithConcat(string inputString, string originalXpath)
    {
        if (!inputString.Contains('\''))
        {
            return string.Format(originalXpath, inputString);
        }
        
        string replacementString = "concat('" + inputString.Replace("'", "', \"'\", '") + "')"; // Replace single quotes and concatenate with 'concat' function
        string finalString = originalXpath.Replace("'{0}'", replacementString); // Replace the placeholder '{0}' in the original XPath with the replacement string
        return finalString;
    }
}
```

Equivalent Java code is:

```
public static String FormatWithConcat(String inputString, String originalXpath) {
    if (!inputString.contains("'")) {
        return String.format(originalXpath, inputString);
    }

    String replacementString = "concat('" + inputString.replaceAll("'", "', \"'\", '") + "')";
    String finalString = originalXpath.replace("'{0}'", replacementString);
    return finalString;
}
```

[.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/yC48Ww)