# How to deal with xpath with apostrophe

Tags: selenium, xpath, automation, apostrophe

The web element contains apostrophe, so I do not know how to create the xpath in my selenium automation script.

The script part is

```
WebElement settingSection = FindElements(By.XPath(string.Format(".//*[.='{0}']", **category**))).FirstOrDefault(x => x.Displayed);
```

the variable category will be "**Sort 'Browse Publications' filter:**", but it could not work when run the automation

[image]

I tried the way with escape apostrophe, but it does not work either.

[image]

[image]
[image]

```
WebElement settingSection = FindElements(By.XPath(string.Format(".//*[.=\"{0}\"]", category))).FirstOrDefault(x => x.Displayed);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use apostrophe (') in xpath while finding element using webdriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37542773/how-to-use-apostrophe-in-xpath-while-finding-element-using-webdriver)

Comment: Please share exception details,

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
String category = "Sort \'Browse Publications\' filter:";
WebElement settingSection = FindElements(By.XPath(string.Format(".//*[.='{0}']", category))).FirstOrDefault(x => x.Displayed);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this xPath:

```
//h3[contains(., 'Browse Publications') and contains(., 'filter')]
```

The sample code is somethig like this:

```
String category = "//h3[contains(., 'Browse Publications') and contains(., 'filter')]";
WebElement settingSection = FindElements(By.XPath(category)).FirstOrDefault(x => x.Displayed);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with following WebElement

```
WebElement settingSection=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//h3[text()=\"Sort 'Browse Publications' filter:\"]"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Find out a solution:

```
WebElement settingSection = FindElements(By.XPath(string.Format(".//*[.=\"{0}\"]", category))).FirstOrDefault(x => x.Displayed);
```