# Locator issue for element which has apostrophe (') in text

Tags: selenium, xpath

I have to find text -'To' email address is formatted incorrectly- using xpath. Below xpath is working well for me

```
(//*[contains(.,"'To' email address is formatted incorrectly.")])[5]
```

But when I put this xpath in my locator.

```
@FindBy(xpath="(//*[contains(.,"'To' email address is formatted incorrectly.")])[5]") public WebElement incorrectEmailFormatLabel;
```

I am getting warning error message in code. I know this is because of double quotes used("'To'..."), but if I change it to single quote(''To'...') I get this error message

```
invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression (//*[contains(.,''To' email address is formatted incorrectly.')])[5]
```

Let me know how to resolve it? I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37542773/how-to-use-apostrophe-in-xpath-while-finding-element-using-webdriver) post also, here xpath is not working for me.

```
(//*[contains(.,\" 'To' email address is formatted incorrectly.\")])[5]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the question, you provided the [excepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37542997/8179099) shows using `\` helps!

Try this:

```
@FindBy(xpath="(//*[contains(.,\"\'To\' email address is formatted incorrectly.\")])[5]") public WebElement incorrectEmailFormatLabel;
```

Hope this helps!